# Incorrect syntax on SQL CommandText

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to build a SQL query and will be passing a string as a parameter. However, I'm getting and incorrect syntax error. I've printed out the values and all seems fine to me though.

I have a string "sqlString" which is built through a series of concatenations, producing this:

```
sqlString = " and (event_id=60 OR event_id=61 OR event_id=56 OR event_id=73)"

SqlCommand totalCmd = new SqlCommand();

totalCmd.CommandText = "SELECT sum(datediff(hour,[event_start],[event_end])) as Timeworked FROM event WHERE (event_start >= @StartDate and event_end <= @EndDate) @mySqlString";

totalCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", txtStartDate.Text);
totalCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", txtEndDate.Text);
totalCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mySqlString", sqlString);

totalDT = SqlComm.SqlDataTable(totalCmd);
```

This is producing an error

> Incorrect syntax near '@mySqlString'

I've ran this query directly in SQL by entering in the parameters, and it runs fine. What is the issue with passing the `mySqlString` parameter?

Comment: You're trying to inject SQL. Parameters prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add `sqlString` as a parameter. You should concatenate it directly to the CommandText instead:

```
totalCmd.CommandText = "SELECT sum(datediff(hour,[event_start],[event_end])) as Timeworked FROM event WHERE (event_start >= @StartDate and event_end <= @EndDate) " + sqlString;
```

The whole point (besides being tidy) of adding values to the `Parameters` instead of concatenating is to clean the values for malicious commands - i.e. the parameters should only be pure values. So the way you do it now, the `sqlString` is interpreted as a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack, and will essentially be purged by that check.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `@` symbol in front of your parameters, like this:

```
totalCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", txtStartDate.Text);
totalCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", txtEndDate.Text);
totalCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySqlString", sqlString);
```

> Note: The syntax you had was not finding a match, so the parameter value was not being substituted, thus it was passing `@mySqlString` in the query.

Comment: That ended up not being the issue here, but thank you for your note.  I will incorporate that as well.